# How to call web service hosted in IIS using JQuery and AngularJS

Tags: jquery, .net, angularjs

I want to use web service using JQuery In Hybrid app. For That i have created html page using AngularJS.

```
<form id="form1" ng-controller="EmpCtrl" ng-submit="save()">     
    <div style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px; margin-left: 450px;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right;">Id :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtEmpID" ng-model="EmpID" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right;">First Name :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtEmpFirstName" ng-model="EmpFirstName" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right;">Last Name :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtEmpLastName" ng-model="EmpLastName" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right;">Address :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea id="txtEmpAddress" cols="20" rows="2" ng-model="EmpAddress"></textarea>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right;">City :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtCity" ng-model="EmpCity" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right;">Pin Code :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtPinCode" ng-model="EmpPincode"    />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right;">State :
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtState" ng-model="EmpState" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right;">Country :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtCountry" ng-model="EmpCountry" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="button" id="btnFetch" value="Fetch" ng-click="getEmployee()"/>
        </div>

        <div id="divTesting">
        </div>
```

And create JQuery. In which i defined ng-app and ng-controller:

```
function EmpCtrl($scope)
{
  $scope.getEmployee = function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'http://www.athithi.com/EmpService.asmx/GetEmployeeDetails',
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",            
      success: function (data) {                
        var TableContent = 
            "<table border='0'>" +
            "<tr>" +
                "<td>ID</td>" +
                "<td>First Name</td>" +
                "<td>Last Name</td>" +
                "<td>Address</td>" +
                "<td>City</td>" +
                "<td>PinCode</td>" +
                "<td>State</td>" +
                "<td>Country</td>" +
            "</tr>";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
            TableContent += "<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + data.d[i].ID + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data.d[i].FirstName + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data.d[i].LastName + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data.d[i].Address + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data.d[i].City + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data.d[i].Pincode + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data.d[i].State + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data.d[i].Country + "</td>" +
                            "</tr>";                
            TableContent += "</table>";
            $("#divTesting").html(TableContent);
        }
      },
      error: function (msg) {
        alert("Error");
      }
    });
  };
  $scope.save = function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "EmpService.asmx/InsertEmployee",
      data: "{'empID':'" + $scope.EmpID + "','firstName':'" + $scope.EmpFirstName + "','lastName':'" + $scope.EmpLastName + "','address':'" + $scope.EmpAddress + "','city':'" + $scope.EmpCity + "','pincode':'" + $scope.EmpPincode + "','state':'" + $scope.EmpState + "','country':'" + $scope.country + "'}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
      },
      error: function (msg) {
        alert("err hello");
      }
    });
  };
}
```

It's work fine when i use url: `EmpService.asmx/InsertEmployee` and  url: `EmpService.asmx/GetEmployeeDetails`  but when i use Hosted IIS web service (`http://www.athithi.com/EmpService.asmx/InsertEmployee('')` and `http://www.athithi.com/EmpService.asmx/GetEmployeeDetails`) it does not work. properly.

Comment: Try to get the actual error message by replacing your error callback of `alert("err hello")` with `console.log(msg)`. You will probably end up with an error message that looks something like `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Mr Isim i am getting same error message(No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource). how can we remove that error.

Comment: Just gonna say, Angular has everything you need built in, why on earth would you use jQuery as well. For DOM manipulation Angular does it so much better than what you've done. And you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @PrinceBhardwaj Did my answer help to resolve your problem?

Comment: thanks @isim, your answer help me to solve my problem. it's working, Now i am  retrieving data from database using web service in Jquery with cross domain functionality . I have one question, Can you  help me to insert data using web service in jquery with cross domain functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are seeing the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error is because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) restriction on Javascript. In other words,  if your HTML pages are hosted under the domain `www.example.com`, then you can only make AJAX requests to services located at exactly the same domain i.e. `www.example.com`.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3076414/1144203) contains ways to get around this restriction.

But in your case, we will try to make things simple for you:

First of all, you can try deploy your client codes (HTML, JQuery, AngularJS) to the same domain http://www.athithi.com (presumably, the same IIS?) as your web service. If you can package your client codes and web services codes into one application, then you won't even need to specify the domain in your AJAX calls.

If that doesn't work, you can update your jquery codes to specified the `dataType` of your ajax call to be `jsonp` like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://www.athithi.com/EmpService.asmx/GetEmployeeDetails',
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "jsonp", // change data type to jsonp
  crossDomain: true, // enable cross-domain requests
  success: function (data) { .. }
  ...
});
```

Finally, if you have administrative privilege over the IIS, you can enable the `access-control-allow-origin` settings in the `web.config` file by doing this (replace `<client_url>` with where your client will be hosted):

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="<client_url>" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
<system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server is throwing this error:

> Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/InsertEmployee'

Which most of the time means HTTP GET and HTTP POST are disabled for WebServices on your server. To enable them adjust your web.config according to:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: you are right Mr Amini. That service giving error because we did not pass the parameter. But Mr Amini i defined all the thing in Jquery even than i always get error message when i used 
url: "http://www.athithi.com/EmpService.asmx/InsertEmployee" service instead of url: "EmpService.asmx/InsertEmployee",